# Auto downloading from akami.net

Tags: mac, macos, data-transfer

I'm running macOS Sierra. Currently I am facing an issue the data received in the system is increasing without any downloading. The firewall showing the system downloading data from the akamai.net.

How can I disable this hidden downloads?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Network tab in Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

[akamai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) is a CDN [content delivery network], used by Apple and others.

In itself it is not suspicious.

The method most people seem to use to prevent unwanted data transfer by any app or system component would be to use [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) [no affiliation, merely a satisfied user].

I would be very careful, though, about blocking Apple's own data transfer, as it could cause issues with updates, iCloud etc.